# Error 706 occured while accessing the hbase subsystem(trafodion)

Tags: hbase

> [trafodion@cdh6 scripts]$ sqlci Apache Trafodion Conversational
>   Interface 2.0.0 Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Apache Software Foundation
>
> > initialize trafodion;
>
> *** ERROR[1398] Error 706 occured while accessing the hbase subsystem. Fix that error and make sure hbase is up and running. Error Details:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
>   org.trafodion.sql.HBaseClient.(HBaseClient.java:102)

I'm sure hbase is working fine and trafodion has been started successfully!

Comment: maybe you should add hbase libs to trafodion CLASSPATH, and may you reformat your post, put the error in code style ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree with sel-fish, this is likely a CLASSPATH issue.

As you say, Trafodion may have started ok, but for some reason the sqlci tool does not have the HBase classes in its CLASSPATH. Here are a few suggestions:

```
# make sure Trafodion is up and running, should show no processes as "down"
sqcheck

# make sure we have the right environment set up
echo $MY_SQROOT
echo $CLASSPATH

# try initialize SQL
sqlci
initialize trafodion
```

Could you send the output of these commands (except for sqlci, which we already saw)? If $MY_SQROOT is not set, source in the sqenv.sh file in your Trafodion installation directory. That might be the cause of the problem:

```
cd <trafodion install directory>
. ./sqenv.sh
sqlci
```

Comment: Also, if you want a quick reply, send an email to user@trafodion.incubator.apache.org with a brief summary and link to your stackoverflow.com question.